Confusion regarding Adams spectral sequence and unoriented cobordism
So this probably the simplest (and thus trivial) place to look at the Adams spectral sequence but I thought it would be good for understanding since I know what the unoriented cobordism ring should look like.
Via the Poyntragin Thom construction we know that the cobordism ring is $\pi_*(MO)$, i.e. $\bigoplus_n\pi_n(MO)$ where $\pi_n(MO)$ is the $n$th stable homotopy group of the Thom spectrum $MO(n)$. We want to use the Adams spectral sequence to calculate the homotopy groups. Let $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z[x_1,\dots]$ have grading $|x_i|=i$, then the $n$th stable homotopy group, should be the vector subspace of $(\mathbb Z/2\mathbb [x_1,\dots])_n$ with basis $$\{x_{i_1}\cdots x_{i_k}:(i_1,\dots, i_k)\text{ is a non dyadic partition of $n$}\}$$
Now I have already shown that $H^*(MO)$ is a free module over the mod $2$ steenrod algebra $\mathfrak a_2$, so applying the Adams spectral sequence should be really very easy. Indeed, we have that:
\begin{align}
E_2^{s,t}=\operatorname{Ext}_{\mathfrak a_2}^s(H^t(MO),\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z)
\end{align}
which is zero for all $s\geq 1$ because $H^*(MO)$ is free over $\mathfrak a_2$, so our spectral sequence stabilizes at the second page. For $s=0$ we have that $E_2^{0,t}=\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathfrak a_2}(H^t(MO),\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z) $. Via the Thom isomorphism, we have that $$H^t(MO)\cong H^{t+k}(MO(k))\cong H^t(BO_k)\cong (\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z[x_1,\dots, x_k])_t$$
for all $k\geq t$.
I believe that the Adams spectral sequence now tells us that that $\pi_t(MO)\otimes \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z\cong \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathfrak a_2}(H^t(MO),\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z)$, but how do I conclude from this that $\pi_t(MO)$ is what it should be?
Thank you for the help.
Edit: It seems I messed up the internal grading, we should have:
$$E_2^{s,t}=\operatorname{Ext}_{\mathfrak a_2}^{s,t}(H^*(MO),\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z)$$
where the $t$ grading is induced by $H^*(MO)$. Here since the only groups which stay alive are $\operatorname{Hom}$ groups, the $\operatorname{Hom}^t_{\mathfrak a_2}(H^*(MO),\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z)$ is precisely the homomorphisms which have support contained in $H^n(MO)$.

Use that $\pi_n(MO)$ is a $\pi_0(MO) = \mathbb{Z}/2$-module.

How does this help other than getting rid of the tensor product?

Well, your description of the Hom groups is correct. Also $H^\ast(MO)\cong H^\ast(BO)$ as groups and $H^\ast(BO) = \mathbb{Z}/2[x_1, x_2,\ldots]$ with $\vert x_i\vert =i$ as graded rings, so what else do you think you are missing?

I need to determine the rank of that Hom group but have no idea how.

In this case $\mathfrak{a}_2$-linear maps are the same as $\mathbb{Z}/2$-linear maps. Does that help?

Wouldn’t that imply that the rank of this Hom group is just the rank of $H^t(MO)$? This seems incorrect…I think the $\mathfrak a_2$ linear maps are zero on certain generators because of the Steenrod squares

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I have answered my own question here :https://mathoverflow.net/questions/483504/an-attempt-at-an-alternative-calculation-of-the-rank-of-pi-nmo/483593#483593

Since $\pi_n(MO)$ is a $\pi_0(MO) = \mathbb{Z}/2$-module, $\pi_n(MO)\cong \pi_n(MO)\otimes \mathbb{Z}/2$ and you can read off the homotopy groups immediately once you determine the $E_2$-page.
If $R_\ast$ is a graded ring and $M_\ast, N_\ast$ are $R_\ast$-modules, then $\mathrm{Hom}_{R_\ast}(M_\ast, N_\ast)$ consists in degree $i$ of the $R_\ast$-linear maps of degree $-i$, i.e. a map $f\colon M_s\to N_{s-i}$ (this a convention for the Adams spectral sequence, usually it would be $+i$).
If you have shown that $H^\ast(MO)$ is a free $\mathfrak{a}_2$-module, then you should know that there is an isomorphism $$H^\ast(MO)\cong\mathfrak{a}_2\otimes \mathbb{Z}/2[x_i:i\neq 2^n-1],$$
where $x_i$ lives in degree $i$. In other words, the $x_i$ form a basis of $H^\ast(MO)$ as an $\mathfrak{a}_2$-module. Now we obtain $$\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathfrak{a}_2}(H^\ast(MO),\mathbb{Z}/2)\cong \mathbb{Z}/2[y_i:i\neq 2^n-1]$$
by mapping $y_i$ to the dual of $x_i$.
Note that this does not tell you anything about the ring structure.

As I said in the comment, doesn't this imply that the rank of $\pi_n(MO)$ has dimension equal to partitions of $n$ has a $\mathbb Z_2$ vector space? Which is incorrect as it should have rank equal to the non dyadic partitions of $n$.

You're right. You need to take the structure of $H^\ast(MO)$ as $\mathfrak{a}_2$-module in account. I fixed it.
